# Override current post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the latest Wordpress with WooCommerce installed.

My goal is when the product page is accessed, to override the current post with a predefined post so the latter is loaded.

For example using www.SITE.COM/?product=my_product to be handled as if ?post=1 was given (predefined post with id = 1).

It feels to me that I need to override $wp_query at early stages because the GLOBALS['post'] is initialized using the value of $wp_query as in the following diagram:

But, I am not sure how to do it.

Telling me how WooCommerce handles the get parameter **?product**=my_product to determine the active page would help or give ideas. I cannot find out how WC does that.

[image: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts]

Comment: You're looking for the `pre_get_posts` hook. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: I printed the $query object inside the action. I understand that the system creates a query that depends on the url, but I cannot see any reference to that, and more importantly, I cannot see any reference on how to override the current post that was set by the system (using URL).